# I got error when I use ngPrint

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I develop gulp application. there are I use ngPrint for print table.

This is module include,

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngPrint']);
```

and html code like this,

```
<h1 id="printThisElement">Hello Bro!</h1>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-print print-element-id="printThisElement">
```

I use for that development this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HkTTHfeLM8buwbWqHuOm?p=preview).

below my error,

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module lgps due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngPrint due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngPrint' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ngPrint
at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:68:12
at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:2005:17
at ensure (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:1929:38)
at module (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:2003:14)
at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4435:22
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:340:20)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4419:5)
at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4436:40
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:340:20)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4419:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngPrint&p1=Error%3A…dModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fvendor%2Fangular.js%3A4419%3A5)
at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:68:12
at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4458:15
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:340:20)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4419:5)
at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4436:40
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:340:20)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4419:5)
at createInjector (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:4344:11)
at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:1676:20)
at bootstrap (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:1697:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=lgps&p1=Error%3A%20…otstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fvendor%2Fangular.js%3A1697%3A12)
```

How I solve that question I try lots way but I can't get result.

Comment: well, it's working perfectly fine in the plunkr . so try again by copying the plunkr code!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests angular cant find ngPrint module. Did you include the required js files ?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/gilf/ngPrint/master/ngPrint.min.css" />
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/gilf/ngPrint/master/ngPrint.min.js"></script>
```

Cheers